# What is the expected date format in the YAML frontmatter of a post in Jekyll?

Tags: datetime, jekyll

According to [Jekyll's frontmatter](http://jekyllrb.com/docs/frontmatter/) documentation, a `date` variable can be used to specify a date and time of when the post was published. Which date format is Jekyll expecting here? Some examples I've seen show, e.g:

```
date: 2010-09-15 14:40:45
```

but is it possible to also include time zone information? How is Jekyll going to parse this string?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When building paths Jekyll will only parse the date portion and ignore the time part.

In a template calling `page.date` will return the date/time of the post or the full date / time from the front matter if included.

You can include a UTC offset in the date `YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS +/-TTTT`

Comment: Just submitted a pull request to add this to the frontmatter documentation page, as I had the same question.

Comment: I assume it would look like this `date: 2015-04-28 12:40:45 +0002`, but how can I display the correct time (or at least the time zone). This doesn't work: `{{ page.date | date: "%H:%M:%S %z" }}` ?